# Does the Antonov An-225 have an Auxiliary Power Unit (APU)?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-systems, apu, antonov-225

[image: Antonov An-225 tail view, no APU]
[image: Airbus A380 tail view with APU]

Most APUs are installed in the rear, see the above image of an Airbus A380 as an example. On the An-225, no APU exhaust is visible at the rear of the aircraft.

So does the An-225 have an APU, and if yes, where is it located?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### No. It doesn't have *an* APU — it has two of them.

They are located close to the main landing gears. From [An-225 Mriya is the world’s largest aircraft (English version)](https://gelio.livejournal.com/193025.html):

> Auxiliary power plant consisting of two TA-12 turbofans installed in the left and right chassis fairings provides independent power to all systems and starts the engines.

I think "turbofans" is not the proper term here. Actually the TA-12 is (just) a gas turbine ([Wiki (Russian)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%90-12), [Google translation](https://translate.google.de/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%25D0%25A2%25D0%2590-12)).

The location of the APUs being much closer to the tarmac might be a reason why Copenhagen airport has (or had) special regulations for its operation on an An-225 ([source](https://web.archive.org/web/20130509130529/http://www.boeing.com/commercial/noise/copenhagen.html)):

> Special regulations for AN124 and AN225.
>   Aeroplane type AN124 and AN225 must not operate their APU unless the pavement
>   underneath is protected against heat and blast effects from the exhaust.

I couldn't find a better picture but the exhaust pipe is quite visible here (red circle):

[image]
([Source](https://generalaviationnews.com/2018/10/04/worlds-largest-airplane-comes-to-the-west-coast/))

I'm not perfectly sure whether the green circle marks the intake, but I guess so.

Comment: The pictures are tremendously beautiful. Thank you for the information and all the pictures.

Comment: @AirCraftLover You mean the pictures from the [first link](https://gelio.livejournal.com/193025.html)? Yes, indeed, they are awesome. To me, the An-225 is one of the most beautiful aircraft ever. Together with the Queen (B747) and the Concorde.

Comment: Yes, the first link, containing various picture of the An-225.

Comment: actually the picture above is not quite correct, i have seen a video of the AN225 on the taxiway and saw the door near the rear for the APU intake (in blue) and RED for the APU exhaust in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChD0O.jpg).